# Relative positioning works in chrome with a block child element but not with inline-block or inline child element

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position

I was trying to create a page and used relative positioning to center (top:45%) a button `header__main__button` in my header `header__main` but it seems like in chrome, relative positioning works on block child elements only as it works with block but not inline or inline-block but one thing to know that it works on all three on **Firefox** and **IE11**. I have a specified width and height also to the parent element.

I have taken care of all browser support features and I have used a feature clip-path which doesn't support in IE11.

Since this project is big, I have shown only partial useful part. Rest is all fine.
Here's the code.

**index.html:**

```
<div class="header__main">
    <div class="header__main__brand"></div>
    <div class="header__main__text">
    <h1 class="header__main__text--big">OUTDOORS</h1>
    <h2 class="header__main__text--small">IS WHERE LIFE HAPPENS</h2> 
</div>
<div class="header__main__button">
    <a class="header__main__button--link" href="#">DISCOVER OUR TOURS</a>
        <span class="header__main__button--animElement"></span>
     </div>
</div>
```

**_header_main.scss:**

```
.header__main{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,$yellow_green_color -40%, 
$dark_sea_green_color) , url("../../images/background__img.jpg");
    height: 90vh;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 80%,0% 100%);

    &__text{
        position: relative;
        top: 30%;
        color: $color_white;

        &--big{
            letter-spacing: 1.5rem;
            font-size: 3rem;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        &--small{
            font-size: 1rem;
            letter-spacing: 0.8rem;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

    }

    &__button{
        position: relative;
        top: 45%;
        display: inline-block;

        &--link{
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: $dark_sea_green_color;
            height: 2.8rem;
            width:12.625rem;
            border-radius: 1.5rem;
            background: $color_white;
            font-size: 0.9rem;
        }

        &--animElement{
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 2.8rem;
            width: 12.625rem;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it to a position that inline-block `header__main__button` element which is not happening in **Chrome** only.

Comment: Next time please post CSS and not (unprocessed) SCSS or LESS.

Comment: I know that there are other ways to implement the same design but the question is that why this way is not working. I want to understand this so as to make me better in this field. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

This does seem like a Chrome bug. However, is there a particular reason relative positioning was used? Relative positioning is best used to make small adjustments. Otherwise it's better to use something else. In this case, you may as well use more absolute positioning?

```css
.header__main {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#9acd32 -40%,#8fbc8f);
    height: 90vh;
    background-position: 50%;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0,100% 0,100% 80%,0 100%);
}
.header__main__text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
.header__main__text--big {
    letter-spacing: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.header__main__text--small {
    font-size: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: .8rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.header__main__button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
.header__main__button--link {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #8fbc8f;
    height: 2.8rem;
    width: 12.625rem;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: .9rem;
}
.header__main__button--animElement {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2.8rem;
    width: 12.625rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__main">
    <div class="header__main__brand"></div>
    <div class="header__main__text">
    <h1 class="header__main__text--big">OUTDOORS</h1>
    <h2 class="header__main__text--small">IS WHERE LIFE HAPPENS</h2> 
</div>
<div class="header__main__button">
    <a class="header__main__button--link" href="#">DISCOVER OUR TOURS</a>
        <span class="header__main__button--animElement"></span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that there are other ways to implement the same design but the question is that why this way is not working. I want to understand this so as to make me better in this field. Thanks for your response

Comment: Like I said, it's a bug in Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=778366

Percentage values for the `top` property aren't computed correctly on elements with `display:inline-block`.  I dislike spending time searching out bug reports, but there it is.